# Extracting a value from a pd dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe column such as below.

{"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/film%20&%20video/narrative%20film"}},"color":16734574,"parent_id":11,"name":"Narrative Film","id":31,"position":13,"slug":"film & video/narrative film"}

I want to extract the info  against the word 'slug'. (In this instance it is *film & video/narrative film*) and store the info as a new dataframe column.

How can I do this ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a (nested) dictionary with different kinds of entries, so it does not make much sense to treat it as a DataFrame column. You could treat it as a DataFrame row, with the dictionary keys giving the column names:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/film%20&%20video/narrative%20film"}}, 
        "color":16734574, "parent_id":11, "name":"Narrative Film", "id":31, "position":13, 
        "slug":"film & video/narrative film"}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict, index=[0])
display(df)
```

Output:

```
    urls  color     parent_id  name            id  position  slug
0   NaN   16734574  11         Narrative Film  31  13        film & video/narrative film
```

Note that the `urls` entry is not recognized, due to the sub-dictionary.

In any case, this does yield `slug` as a column, so please let me know if this answers your question.

Of course you could also extract the `slug` entry directly from your dictionary:

```
dict['slug']
```